# How can I dismiss Windows notifications from GCal without opening their tab?

Tags: windows-10, firefox, notifications, google-calendar

I use Google Calendar through Firefox, and have given it permission to send me desktop notifications; I like and appreciate getting a desktop notification of an upcoming event. However, I want to see/acknowledge/dismiss the notification without interrupting what I'm doing.

Currently, when I click "dismiss" on the notification popup, I'm taken *out* of whatever other tab/entirely other app I'm in and moved over to the GCal tab of Firefox. This is useless, since the notification has already given me the information I need. Clicking on the notification *body* bringing you to its tab makes sense. But clicking on *dismiss* should clearly just dismiss and nothing else.

I'm pretty sure i *used* to have this function, maybe on a previous computer, or before a windows/firefox update, but I can't remember how I got it. Which setting do I need to change so that dismissing the notification just dismisses it, without changing my focused tab/app?